# ¿Como pasar variables de un formulario a otro si unas vienen cargadas con un select y otras están en un input?

Tags: javascript, php, variables, post, input

Estoy recogiendo unos valores de una select y mostrándolos em el html. Después necesito añadir dos campos mas(día y hora) en dos input. Una vez que esen rellenos esos input, necesito pasar toda la información a otro formulario para recogerlos mediante $_POST o $_GET pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

No se como añadir esos dos input al href.

La web queda así:
[image: Imagen de como llevo la web]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CRM-1.0</title>
    <script>
        function setNombre() {
            var fechacita = document.getElementById('date').value;
            var horacita =  document.getElementById('time').value;
            console.log(fechacita);
            console.log(horacita);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    

<?php

/* header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1'); */

$servername = "localhost";
$database = "admin_id0ct0r2021";
$username = "informatica";
$password = "Informat_2013";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
/* echo "Connected successfully <br>"; */

// Vamos a traer los pedidos que todavía no se han enviado las autorizaciones
$sql = "select ps_orders.id_order, ps_orders.reference, ps_orders.current_state, ps_orders.id_customer, 
ps_product.id_product, ps_product.nombre_proveedor, ps_product.id_supplier, 
ps_supplier.id_supplier, ps_supplier.email as emailpro, ps_supplier.direccionFiscal, 
ps_customer.id_customer, ps_customer.firstname, ps_customer.lastname, ps_customer.email as emailcliente, 
ps_order_detail.product_id, ps_order_detail.id_order, ps_order_detail.product_name, ps_order_detail.product_quantity 
from ps_orders, ps_order_detail, ps_product, ps_supplier, ps_customer 
where ps_orders.id_order = ps_order_detail.id_order 
and ps_order_detail.product_id = ps_product.id_product 
and ps_product.id_supplier = ps_supplier.id_supplier 
and ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer 
and ps_orders.current_state=2 
order by ps_orders.id_order desc";


$resultado = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$resultado) {
    $mensaje  = 'Consulta no válida: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $mensaje .= 'Consulta completa: ' . $consulta;
    die($mensaje);
}
echo "<h2>Pedidos pendientes de enviar autorización</h2>";
echo "<br>";
echo "<table>";
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['id_order'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['reference'] . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['firstname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['lastname'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['emailcliente'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['product_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['nombre_proveedor'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'>" . $fila['emailpro'] . "</td>";    
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='date' onclick='setNombre()' name='date' id='date'><input type='time' onclick='setNombre()' name='time' id='time'></td>";    
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><a href='mail.php?reference=". $fila['reference'] ."&firstname=". $fila['firstname'] ."&lastname=". $fila['lastname'] ."&emailcliente=". $fila['emailcliente'] ."&product_name=". $fila['product_name'] ."&nombre_proveedor=". $fila['nombre_proveedor'] ."&emailpro=". $fila['emailpro'] . "&date=<script>fechacita</script>&time=<script>horacita</script>'>Enviar Autorizaciones</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";



mysqli_close($conn);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Tampoco se si esta es la mejor forma de hacer esto.
No se si seria mejor hacer esto o existen mejores maneras. Soy nuevo en esto y voy aprendiendo poco a poco.
¿Cómo lo veis?

Comment: hay varias formas de hacerlo (revisa SO, que hay varios ejemplos). Lo mas clasico seria envolver el input en un form que lleve al archivo que te interesa, y luego en el archivo ya puedes recibir los datos en la variable $_POST.

Comment: Gracias, pero si envuelvo el input en un form, cuando envío las variables al otro formulario, como tienen el mismo nombre y hay varias lineas, no me coge el valor de la linea a la que pongo dia y hora.

Comment: no entiendo entonces tu caso. lo que quieres es enviar los datos (lo que muestras en los <td> a otro archivo? si es asi, sigue siendo lo mismo, englobar los datos en un form. Quizas es que tienes que preparar varios form (uno por cada linea), pero en el destino solo te llegará los datos de una linea...

Comment: eso, o puedes hacer arrays en los input. Si lo que quieres es lo ultimo, puedes mirar este otro SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073690/post-an-array-from-an-html-form-without-javascript en el que tratan el tema

Comment: Gracias @Jakala. Si meto el form dentro del array me crea diferentes FORM y así se resuelve el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por la ayuda.
Finalmente metiendo el FORM dentro del array, crea diferentes FORM y asi no existe problema de envío de envío.

```
echo "<table>";
while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<form action='mail.php' method='post'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='3px' name='id_order' id='id_order' value= '" . $fila['id_order'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='12px' name='reference' id='reference' value= '" . $fila['reference'] . "'></td>"; 
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='12px' name='firstname' id='firstname' value= '" . $fila['firstname'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='12px' name='lastname' id='lastname' value= '" . $fila['lastname'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' name='emailcliente' id='emailcliente' value= '" . $fila['emailcliente'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='40px' name='product_name' id='product_name' value= '" . $fila['product_name'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' size='40px' name='nombre_proveedor' id='nombre_proveedor' value= '" . $fila['nombre_proveedor'] . "'></td>";
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' name='emailpro' id='emailpro' value= '" . $fila['emailpro'] . "'></td>";    
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='text' name='fecha' id='fecha'><input type='text' name='hora' id='hora'></td>";        
    echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #000000'><input type='submit' value='enviar'/></td>";    
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</form>";
} 
echo "</table>";
```